# Kdb+ drivers for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, kdb

I'd like to use NodeJS to implement a simple REST interface to pull data from Kdb+.

Does anyone know of any existing driver or a project to implement a Kdb+ driver for NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of... but shouldn't be too hard, really. You could simply use the http interface to create calls to kdb and parse the result into json with [Arthur's json implementation](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/e/json.k)

Answer (score 1):

There is https://github.com/michaelwittig/node-q
I've used it in my project and works great.